# lvsd config correct?

Tags: centos, redhat, high-availability

I have used Piranha to setup fail-over for httpd. I set the servers the same, but one shows the VIPS and the other doesn't. Is this normal?

Server A) [Primary]

```
[root@titania ~]# ipvsadm -L
IP Virtual Server version 1.2.1 (size=4096)
Prot LocalAddress:Port Scheduler Flags
  -> RemoteAddress:Port           Forward Weight ActiveConn InActConn
TCP  172.16.28.231:http lblc
  -> 172.16.28.229:http           Route   1      0          0
  -> 172.16.28.230:http           Route   1      0          0
[root@titania ~]

[root@titania ~]# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:15:5D:1C:D4:04
          inet addr:172.16.28.233  Bcast:172.16.28.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::215:5dff:fe1c:d404/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1115300 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:686246 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:115178238 (109.8 MiB)  TX bytes:50225507 (47.8 MiB)

eth0:1    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:15:5D:1C:D4:04
          inet addr:172.16.28.231  Bcast:172.16.28.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:838 (838.0 b)  TX bytes:838 (838.0 b)

[root@titania ~]#

[root@titania ~]# cat /etc/sysconfig/ha/lvs.cf
serial_no = 53
primary = 172.16.28.233
service = lvs
backup_active = 1
backup = 172.16.28.232
heartbeat = 1
heartbeat_port = 539
keepalive = 6
deadtime = 18
network = direct
debug_level = NONE
monitor_links = 1
syncdaemon = 1
syncd_iface = eth0
syncd_id = 0
virtual http {
     active = 1
     address = 172.16.28.231 eth0:1
     vip_nmask = 255.255.255.0
     port = 80
     send = "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n"
     expect = "HTTP"
     use_regex = 0
     load_monitor = none
     scheduler = lblc
     protocol = tcp
     timeout = 6
     reentry = 15
     quiesce_server = 1
     server deimos {
         address = 172.16.28.229
         active = 1
         weight = 1
     }
     server phobos {
         address = 172.16.28.230
         active = 1
         weight = 1
     }
}
[root@titania ~]#
```

Server B) [Secondary]

```
IP Virtual Server version 1.2.1 (size=4096)
Prot LocalAddress:Port Scheduler Flags
  -> RemoteAddress:Port           Forward Weight ActiveConn InActConn
[root@titan ~]#
[root@titan ~]# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:15:5D:1C:34:01
          inet addr:172.16.28.232  Bcast:172.16.28.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::215:5dff:fe1c:3401/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:529515 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:81242 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:31911311 (30.4 MiB)  TX bytes:4919228 (4.6 MiB)
          Interrupt:9 Base address:0x2000

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:236 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:236 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:22532 (22.0 KiB)  TX bytes:22532 (22.0 KiB)

[root@titan ~]#
[root@titan ~]# cat /etc/sysconfig/ha/lvs.cf
serial_no = 51
primary = 172.16.28.233
service = lvs
backup_active = 1
backup = 172.16.28.232
heartbeat = 1
heartbeat_port = 539
keepalive = 6
deadtime = 18
network = direct
debug_level = NONE
monitor_links = 1
syncdaemon = 1
syncd_iface = eth0
syncd_id = 0
virtual http {
     active = 1
     address = 172.16.28.231 eth0:1
     vip_nmask = 255.255.255.0
     port = 80
     send = "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n"
     expect = "HTTP"
     use_regex = 0
     load_monitor = none
     scheduler = lblc
     protocol = tcp
     timeout = 6
     reentry = 15
     quiesce_server = 1
     server deimos {
         address = 172.16.28.229
         active = 1
         weight = 1
     }
     server phobos {
         address = 172.16.28.230
         active = 1
         weight = 1
     }
}
[root@titan ~]#
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is normal and expected behavior for LVS.

Since this is a high availability setup, the load balanced IP (172.16.28.231 in this example) will only reside on the active node.  If you were to stop the pulse daemon on Server A, a failover of the load balanced IP to Server B would automatically occur (assuming the pulse daemon is running and is in a healthy state Server B).  The failover should be nearly instantaneous, and once it has occurred, restart the pulse daemon on Server A.

The commands for this workflow and failover verification are included below:

```
Server_B# service pulse status
pulse (pid  PID_NUMBER) is running...
Server_A# service pulse stop
Server_B# ifconfig # Verify the VIP failed over eth0:X on Server_B
Server_A# service pulse start
```

You will be able to failover back and forth between nodes using this method.